# CSS grid for backoffice

Tags: css, design-patterns, grid

We are developing an intranet backoffice. We've been investigating about safe area, and real viewport size of browsers in different OS.

Since it's internal software, we can "force" users to use browser and resolution we want.  We would like to use 1280x1024 resolution in screens, and Chrome (or Firefox) as default browser.

We've checked with browser window maximized that the viewport size (in Chrome and Firefox) is 1263 pixels width. But we don't want to force so much, I mean, we think in 1240 as maximum width of web design.

Now, playing with CSS Grid generator software, I've found this config:   1240px = 12 columns of 85px each one plus 20px gutter.

What do you think about this ? Is it a good idea flexible enough for a backoffice ?

Any suggestions about this development ?

Thank you in advance

P.D. By the way, we were thinking about using BlueTrip CSS grid modified to 1240px ...

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any point why you should limit your intranet app for certain browsers. In fact it may cause you more problems (browsers updates may break some layouts and elements since you are not forced to do proper cross-browser testing, monitor upgrades with different screen resolution). So, if it is flexible enough? No. Is the 12 columns grid enough? May be, depends on use. I would prefer to use fluid grid, responsible web design and media queries.

Comment: The fact is that we can choose the monitor resolution and the browser we want them to use ... it's not free user choice. The "desktop" icon will launch the browser we want, and the monitor will have already the resolution we want.  Also, it's a backoffice with long and complex forms, the "agents" (users) are used to old Windows application ... the input #34 have to be in the same place always , you know ;)